# LLVM back-end can only promote 2 allocas to registers, even if there are unused physical registers

Tags: llvm

I'm using MCJIT in a CPU emulator project, the IR is mainly generated using IRBuilder and it works, but the performance is worse than our old JIT. I compared the code generated, the main problem is related to register usage. In LLVM, I promoted 5 local variables to registers by putting allocas at the beginning of the IR function, after run "createPromoteMemoryToRegisterPass", all 5 variables are promoted to virtual registers with PHI nodes in the optimized IR. But in the final X64 binary code, only 2 variables are promoted to registers, the other 3 spill. And in the code there are still 2 registers unused(R11, R12).

I've tried using llc to compile the optimized IR with greedy/pbqp, the results are same, only 2 got promoted.

I've spent a lot of time on this issue, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Code snippet:

IR before optimization:

```
define void @emulate(%struct.fpga_cpu* %pcpu, i64 %pc_arg, i64 %r0_arg, i64 %r1_arg, i64 %r2_arg, i64 %r3_arg) {
entry:
  %0 = alloca i64
  %1 = alloca i64
  %2 = alloca i64
  %3 = alloca i64
  %4 = alloca i64
  %5 = alloca i64
  store i64 %r0_arg, i64* %2
  store i64 %r1_arg, i64* %3
  store i64 %r2_arg, i64* %4
  store i64 %r3_arg, i64* %5
  store i64 %pc_arg, i64* %0
....
}
```

IR after optimization:

```
  define void @emulate(%struct.fpga_cpu* %pcpu, i64 %pc_arg, i64 %r0_arg, i64 %r1_arg, i64 %r2_arg, i64 %r3_arg) {
....
  %.01662 = phi i64 [ %r2_arg, %entry ], [ %.21664, %cmp ]
  %.01648 = phi i64 [ %r1_arg, %entry ], [ %.21650, %cmp ]
  %.01640 = phi i64 [ %r0_arg, %entry ], [ %.21642, %cmp ]
  %.01636 = phi i64 [ %r3_arg, %entry ], [ %.21638, %cmp ]
  %.0 = phi i64 [ %pc_arg, %entry ], [ %.2, %cmp ]
....
}
```

The X64 code:

```
emulate:                         
pushq   %rbp
pushq   %r15
pushq   %r14
pushq   %r13
pushq   %r12
pushq   %rbx
subq    $72, %rsp
movq    %r9, 56(%rsp)           # 8-byte Spill
movq    %r8, 64(%rsp)           # 8-byte Spill
movq    %rcx, %r15
movq    %rdx, %r13
movq    %rdi, %r14    
....
r2_arg, r3_arg spill, but R11,R12 are never used.
....
retq
```

Comment: I believe a small reproducible example could make your problem significantly easier to understand.

Comment: Sorry for my vague question, I can't post working code here due to company policy. The basic idea here is to let the emulated CPU's register variables living in X64 registers.